# Displaying only part of a text in an SQL column

Tags: sql

I have a list of outstations (sites with a local controller at them) that roughly follow the below format:
`city.department.suburb.street_name.outstation`
Some outstations, however, have more details between 'department' and 'oustation'. e.g.:
`city.department.district.suburb.street_name.outstation`.
The number of 'extra details' between department and outstation is variable (usually between 2-5 delimited by a full stop)

I would like to display the outstations in the following format:

```
City        Department      Site                                Outstation
Brisbane    Wastewater      Fortitude Valley, Pump Station      ABC123
Townsville  Water           Northern, Paluma, Reservoir         DEF456
Cairns      Wastewater      Suburb, Asset                       XYZ789
```

basically, regardless of how much stuff is between 'department' and 'outstation', I want it all to be displayed in 'site'

For City and Department, its pretty easy to go Element(1, '.',Table.FullName,0) AS "City"
But I cant find a way to dynamically change the number of elements for Site.
Also for Outstation I cant find a way to go Element(n, '.',Table.FullName,0), where n is the number of elements (i.e. select the last element)

Comment: Please edit your question to make it readable. There is a [?] button, top right of the edit field, to help you. Also, please tag your dbms.

Comment: I would also give some full examples of the raw data and expected output. It's a little confusing to figure out the pattern you're trying to parse out

Comment: "sql" is not helpful as a tag (eg: if you use "sql-server" please use "sql-server"  tag instead). Each dbms vendor has substantial differences in their SQL implementations. **nb** it helps **you** if we propose the syntax that **you** will need. Please use the **edit tags** link at the right of the tag you have already.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '.', 1) AS City,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '.', 2), '.', -1) AS Department,
    REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '.', LENGTH(mycolumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(mycolumn, '.', '')) + 1),
            '.',
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '.', LENGTH(mycolumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(mycolumn, '.', '')) + 1)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '.', LENGTH(mycolumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(mycolumn, '.', '')) + 1), '.', ''))
        ),
        '.',
        ', '
    ) AS Site,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '.', -1) AS Outstation
FROM mytable;
```

| City | Department | Site | Outstation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brisbane | Wastewater | Brisbane, Wastewater, Fortitude, Valley, Pump, Station | ABC123 |
| Townsville | Water | Townsville, Water, Northern, Paluma, Reservoir | DEF456 |
| Cairns | Wastewater | Cairns, Wastewater, Suburb, Asset | XYZ789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-xq8V3kF)

**Postgres**

```
SELECT 
    SPLIT_PART(mycolumn, '.', 1) AS City,
    SPLIT_PART(mycolumn, '.', 2) AS Department,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING(mycolumn FROM POSITION('.' IN mycolumn) + 1), 
        CONCAT('.', SPLIT_PART(mycolumn, '.', -1)),
        ''
    ) AS Site,
    SPLIT_PART(mycolumn, '.', -1) AS Outstation
FROM mytable;
```

| city | department | site | outstation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brisbane | Wastewater | Wastewater.Fortitude.Valley.Pump.Station | ABC123 |
| Townsville | Water | Water.Northern.Paluma.Reservoir | DEF456 |
| Cairns | Wastewater | Wastewater.Suburb.Asset | XYZ789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BRJBpJJx)

Comment: Perhaps now you can see why we need to know exactly which dbms you are using